# What are the product(s) of red phosphorous when burned?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, combustion

A match box lighter strip typically consists of powdered glass and red phosphorous. When this part is burned, it's residue is like a sticky dust that, when applying friction, will release smoke or vapor. You can do it with you fingers and it looks really cool.

So what's the chemistry behind this?

Answer (score 1):

> The major product formed is -  Tetraphosphorus decaoxide ($\ce{P4O10}$)

Infact you could have googled it. There are many interesting videos on youtube.

Check this out -  [Burning of Red Phosphorus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CsvSUAwq0uM)